# bash wait for rsync to finish for proceeding

Tags: bash, macos, global-variables

Hi I wrote a bash script for my backup procedure and i monitor a folder and sync the target dir to this folder every month and the changes to a mother dir every day.

I want the second rsync process to start after the first has finished I implemented it with the wait command, but it doesn't work:

```
if [ ! -f $MONTH_COMPARE/monat-$MONTH-compare.log ]; then
   rsync -avh --force --delete --update --log-file=$MONTH_COMPARE/monat-$MONTH-compare.log $SOURCE_LOC $MONTH_COMPARE &
fi
wait

if [[ $MONTH -eq 1] && [ $DAY -eq 1]]; then
    rm -rf $BACKUP_DIR/$LASTYEAR/12
    mkdir $BACKUP_DIR/$LASTYEAR/12

    #compare changes of last month to backup year month
    rsync -avh --force --ignore-errors --log-file=$BACKUP_DIR/$LASTYEAR/12/monat-$MONTH.log --compare-des=$MONTH_COMPARE $SOURCE_LOC $BACKUP_DIR/$LASTYEAR/12 &&
    #update aktuell with day changes
    rsync -avh --force --ignore-errors --delete --update --log-file=$BACKUP_DIR/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/tag-$DAY.log --backup-dir=$BACKUP_DIR/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY $SOURCE_LOC $TARGET_DIR &&
    #update the month compare folder da 1. des neuen monats
    rsync -avh --force --ignore-errors --delete --update --log-file=$MONTH_COMPARE/monat-$MONTH-compare.log $SOURCE_LOC $MONTH_COMPARE &
fi
wait
```

how to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? (eg. does it erase all your data, start a month later, what does it do?).

Answer (score 2):

You are running rsync in the background (&) and then waiting for it. Why not just run it normally (without the &) and so you won't need to wait. The next command will only execute after the first rsync is finished.