# Is there a difference between "background(&) and wait" and simply execute the normal command in bash?

Tags: bash, background, wait

In bash scripts, I have seen codes like this

```
command &
wait
```

I am wondering what is there any motivation behind this operation rather than simply run

```
command
```

instead.

The motivation of this question comes from this post: [bash wait for rsync to finish for proceeding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276034/bash-wait-for-rsync-to-finish-for-proceeding), where the poster chose to use the "wait" method while an unaccepted answer suggests the normal command method.

Although based on my understanding the answer to that post should be correct, I have also seen various other places (including companies and personal projects) where the "background and wait" method is used in practice, so I am getting a bit confused.

Is there any situation where the two codes actually have a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the script

```
trap 'echo bye' SIGINT
sleep 20
```

If `SIGINT` is sent to your script while `sleep` is running, the trap will not execute (and the script will not exit) until `sleep` exits.

Now consider

```
trap 'echo bye' SIGINT
sleep 20 &
wait
```

Now, it's not `sleep` that's blocking the script, but it's own built-in `wait` command. If `SIGINT` is sent to your script, the trap will execute and your script will exit immediately.

Comment: Thank you. In this case, would the sleep be instantly killed as well, or will it exit after 20 seconds?

Comment: @cr001 The answer to that isn't simple and might be worth a research or at least a tedious compilation.  For starters you can check it manually using `ps` or `pgrep`, but there are many factors that may or may not make a subprocess get killed.  There's job control, process disownership, terminal input, double fork, implementation detail, SIGHUP, etc.  Perhaps you can just look at the common outcome if that's good enough for you, but I wouldn't even care about it.  I would use an exit trap that kills if I would want to make it terminate or use a double fork if not.

Comment: @cr001 That question is exactly why I was hesitant to post this answer (along with confusion over the exact mechanism that prevents the script from seeing the signal in the first case. I would have liked to say that `sleep` was "uninterruptible", but in a precise technical sense, `sleep` process is in an interruptible sleep state. Any explanation I might have attempted would probably just be confusingly wrong, so I'm staying silent on the "how" and "why".)